# No progress bar for milestons

Tags: gitlab

Why for all of my milestones (open and close) have: 0% complete
even when I have:
Merge requests 3
Open: 0 Closed: 0 Merged: 3

https://gitlab.com/modding-openmw/modhelpertool/-/milestones?sort=due_date_desc&state=all

Answer (score 1):

### TLDR

You may create some issues, and close one issue to see the progress bar.

### Longer answer

In GitLab, the progress bar of milestones = (the issues you have closed/ all issues included in the milestone)

As you have zero issue in your milestone, you have no progress according to GitLab's rule.

This convention is about agile managements, as all of them (Kanban, Scrum) need requirements(issue) before implementation(coding and MR). Hence, you need to first create some issues in a milestone, then code, then do the MR as you close some issues. And viola, you'll see the progress in the milestone!